# How can I install Micronaut CLI?

Tags: micronaut

I cannot find in the [Micronaut documentation](http://micronaut.io/documentation.html) a way to install mn CLI. There many usage examples, but not a how to install it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no published artifacts yet for micronaut. It is easy to install from source by following the instructions in the README.md

https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core#building-from-source

Published versions will be on sdkman http://sdkman.io/

Comment: Right!  For now if you want to build it yourself you can `./gradlew cli:cZ` which will create `./cli/build/distributions/mn.zip`.  You can extract that somewhere and add the relevant `bin/` to your `PATH`, or you could just add `<path to your Micronaut dir>/cli/build/bin` to your `PATH`.

Comment: great, however, I suggest linking instructions from official documentation

Comment: We haven't shipped the first milestone yet but will in just a few days.  At that point installation instructions will be consistent with the milestone.

Comment: There is a new tweet about this at https://twitter.com/micronautfw/status/999936596936937473 which also mentions a CLI zip

Comment: In wanting to try to play around with micronaut, I learned that I am unable to install SDK man for unknown reasons. Luckily for me, other person has faced this issue, unluckily for me, the issue on git was closed  :https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/677 What was supposed to be a fun and enjoyable experience of trying out the microframework turned into an annoying mess. I would welcome an alternative to SDK man on the official docs.

Answer (score 2):

We are publishing first Milestone next week. There will be a "Download" page in the [website](http://micronaut.io). Stayed tuned

Answer (score 1):

Downloading the code and building works as explained in other answers.  Adding this answer to highlight the fact that Micronaut is  available via `sdkman` beta channel

Edit `$SDKMAN_DIR/etc/config` and enable beta
    sdkman_beta_channel=true

Start new shell and run `sdk install micronaut`